# Why does this query for current month name return the wrong month?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

Why is this query only giving me "January" as output and not the current month?

```
select cast(datename(month,datepart(mm,getdate()))as char(15))
```

Comment: nice explanation . got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `DATEPART` call. `DATENAME`'s second parameter should be a `datetime`; you're trying to feed it an integer.

```
select cast(datename(month,getdate()) as char(15))
```

Update for MS SQL Server 2016 and up: you might find just `FORMAT()`ing  the date easier to read, especially if you are familiar with .NET DateTime format strings:

```
select format(getdate(), 'MMMM')
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Cory's explanation, `datepart(mm,getdate())` gives you a value of 10. Feeding it again to the `datename` function  passes it the date '11 January 1900' as an argument, since the value 10 is treated as 10 days from 1 January 1900. That is why the month returned by `datename` is January.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BAID4336)